# Jersey RESTful: Spring bean creation management

Tags: java, spring, rest, dependency-injection, jersey

I have the following Jersey RESTful web service class to serve the HTTP request/response:

```
@Path("/customer")
public class CustomerService {

    private static ApplicationContext context;
    public static CustomerJDBCTemplate dbController;

    static {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        dbController = (CustomerJDBCTemplate) context.getBean("customerJDBCTemplate");
    }

        //methods for GET/POST requests ...
}
```

Here I use the static variable `dbController` as my DAO object. Since I want to have only one instance of `dbController` in my application, I give it a static property so that all Jersey classes can share the same `dbController` instance. So for example, if I have another Jersey class that uses a DAO, then I can just use it as `CustomerService.dbController.create()` and something like that. But I wonder if this is the correct and most appropriate way to instantiate a DAO bean inside a Jersey class because if the resource at Path: /customer is not called, then the DAO bean is not instantiated.

I can also repeat the above bean instantiation steps in another Jersey class:

```
@Path("/another")
public class AnotherService {

    private static ApplicationContext context;
    public static  CustomerJDBCTemplate dbController;

    static {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        dbController = (CustomerJDBCTemplate) context.getBean("customerJDBCTemplate");
    }

        //methods for GET/POST requests ...
}
```

My question is: Will this create a different instance than the first one? Or are `CustomerService.dbController` and `AnotherService.dbController` refer to the same object?

If I want to use the first DAO object `CustomerService.dbController` in a non-Jersey class (e.g., service layer classes), should I use the first method to create the bean only in one Jersey class as a public static variable and refer it in all classes that use `dbController`? What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 2):

First, if you plan to use Jersey+Spring, I think the jersey-spring integration is [worth checking out](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html).

Also, the whole point of using any Dependency Injection/Inversion Of Control framework is to manage the lifecycle and inter-dependency of "beans". DI/IoC libs and frameworks are here t avoid this static/dependency nightmare and to help you build testable, extensible applications.

[This part of the Spring reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) should make things clearer. By **default**, Spring creates and manages singleton beans for you (one instance shared by all within your application). Check out the [beans scopes documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes).

General rule of thumb: injecting/using directly the application context is somewhat of a code smell (especially if you hardcode the name of your context file!).

If you're looking for best practices, [the Jersey+Spring example should help you](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.4.1/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp).

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the link to Jersey-Spring guide. I read through the example code in the link. I didn't find any bean instantiation using application context `getBean()` method. So where is the bean instantiated in the example code? Is it through `class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig` where `MyApplication` needs to be registered in web.xml?

Comment: Bean instantiation is done by Spring.
You just have to basically describe your application context to Spring (using JavaConfig or XML files) and Spring will take care of the rest (i.e. instantiate + inject).

Note that the getBean only retrieves an existing bean from the application context, meaning it's already been instantiated.

So in that case, the example application registers bean definitions with an [XML file](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.4.1/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp/src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml).

Comment: I understand that bean definitions are in the XML file. But from the example code, there isn't any Java code like `ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml")` to actually instantiate the bean in the [source code](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.4.1/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/helloworld/spring). So I wonder where the applicationContext is instantiated in the example.

Comment: It's set up in the web.xml configuration: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.4.1/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L55

Comment: Thanks Brian. The web.xml is really something I missed. It is hidden so deep that I can't find the bean instantiation :)

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use @**Inject** instead of **static**.
Jersey has its own injection mechanism

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
public MyApplication() {
    register(new FacadeBinder());
```

Register as Singleton

```
public class FacadeBinder extends AbstractBinder {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(MyManager.class).to(MyManager.class);
  }
}
```

Then in your resource endpoint you can use registered classes:

```
@Path("/jersey")
public class MyEndpoint implements MyInterface {
  @Inject
  MyManager myManager;
```

Or you can integrate with some other injection framework such as Guice or Spring.

Comment: Thanks. In my example, the `dbController` is injected through Spring bean configuration file. The reason why I make it static is I want to reuse the same `dbController` bean in another class so that this DAO bean only has one instance in my application. If I use `@Inject` annotation, it will be equivalent to my Spring bean injection. So what is the difference?

Comment: The difference will be in _static_ code in your class. For instance, if you write a unit test you will need to initialize Spring context for this to work which is quite time consuming. Another important thing is String literals in the code. They are error prone on bigger projects.